# Is there any chance to rearrange the execution plan manually?

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-execution-plan

I have 2 tables,

1. Need
2. NeedCategory

Need table has clusted index on needid column, and NeedCategory have composite clustered index on needid and categoryid.

Now take a look on following query and execution plan for the query.

```
 SELECT N.NeedId,N.NeedName,N.ProviderName    
   FROM dbo.Need N    
   JOIN dbo.NeedCategory NC    
     ON nc.NeedId = n.NeedId     
  WHERE IsActive=1      
  AND CategoryId= 2
  ORDER BY NeedName
```

[image: Execution plan]

- Clustered index scan on need table is happens for Isactive= 1.
- Clustered index scan on needcategory table is happens for CategoryId=2

My question is,

1. Why scan happens before the join occurs? if it happens after join then the filter would be lighter. Even if optimizer chooses the scan to execute first.
2. Is there any chance to rearrange the execution plan manually?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

No it would NOT be lighter after join.

Why would you think it would be lighter after the join?

Why would you think it would be better match up on all nc.NeedId = n.NeedId then then filter?
If you filter first then you never have to match up nc.NeedId = n.NeedId that are going to get eliminated anyway.

That relatively cheap Merge Join is a good thing.

Lets say I am matching up socks with shoes and only want red socks. 
Why would I match up a blue sock with a shoes and then eliminate it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let's say your `Need` table has 10,000 rows, of which half has `IsActive = 1`; `NeedCategory` has 100 rows, and 80 has `CategoryID = 2`. Would it be faster to join 10,000 rows to 100 rows then filter the result, or scan the tables to filter the rows before then join operation, matching 5,000 rows to 80 rows?
2. You can affect how the plan is generated within a certain limit. However, be very careful with that. SQL Server often knows the data better than the developer.